# Using Git Locally then merging and checking into StarTeam

Tags: git, git-workflow

My client currently requires us to use StarTeam for checking in our code changes. I would like to pull all the code down from StarTeam and setup a local Git repository so that I might take advantages of the branching to work on some upgrades of some JQuery modules. Does anyone have any suggestions or advice on using a local Git Repository then checking in changes to a StarTeam server?

Comment: My initial thought is to pull down the latest from the StarTeam server, copy the files to a new workspace/directory and create a new Git repository there, make a branch and make all my changes. When it works, do a diff between master and my branch and copy over all the changed files. Then I would need to merge my changes with the StarTeam server. Any better or different ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go a bit like `git-svn` does that kind of workflow:

- import in a Git repo, in the `master` branch
- make all the branches from there, but never committing anything to `master`
- make all the merges between branches other than master (again, the `master` branch is supposed to reflect the StartTeam server latest import)
- when ready to go back to StartTeam:

  - **first update `master`** (with the latest from StartTeam)
  - *then* merge my work back to the `master` branch
  - use the content of that master branch as a source to reimport in StartTeam (meaning at this point, `master` will again represents StarTeam content)

Comment: Still, it's git; you could always keep a StarTeam branch and work off of master. ;)

Comment: @IslandCow: absolutely. It depends on what you want '`master`' to represent.